# SQL Server Report Builder Number Formatting

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I am creating Reports in SQL Server Report builder.

When I set format of any number fields, in design it is displaying sample value.

For e.g. If I set format 0.00 to one numeric field, it started to display 12345.00

I have 10-12 fields in design, it caused very much confusion.

Is there any solution to change this?

When I open report in Visual Studio, it doesn't display like that.

Check Following screenshots:

In Report Builder:

[image: Report Builder]

In Visual Studio:

[image: VisualStudio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got solution:

There is option in toolbar.

[image: Place Holder]

Answer (score 0):

From what you described looks like you have an issue with the regional settings number format.

In your development environment, the decimal values are retrieved correctly, so you got 123.45 instead of 12345.00

In your target environment, the format of the decimal values is different, for example is 123,45 (comma instead of dot) so you get 12345.00

Comment: No, I want to display format 12345.00 , but My problem is report-builder Display.

Comment: I have added screenshots, please check that

Comment: Visual studio displays the field name and not an example value, AFAIK I don't know a settings to change this