# SQL Server Report Builder Field Formatting

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report-builder2.0

I am creating Reports in SQL Server Report builder.

When I set format of any number fields, in design it is displaying sample value.

For e.g. If I set format 0.00 to one numeric field, it started to display 12345.00

I have 10-12 fields in design, it caused very much confusion.

Is there any solution to change this?

When I open report in Visual Studio, it doesn't display like that.

Check Following screenshots:

In Report Builder:

[image]

In Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Earlier this question was asked as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631762/sql-server-report-builder-number-formatting/24774623 
but, no valid answers received.
and, I am still facing this formatting issue.

Comment: Bounty is the SO way to attract more attention and more answers for your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got solution:

There is option in toolbar

[image]